# Instructions are getting lost if there are 2 subtitles, works fine with only 1

Tags: python, color-picker

When instead of location I am putting text value '(255, 255, 255)' in either while and if instructions everything works fine. I have been troubleshooting it for 3 hours now, and I have ran out of ideas. I have made sure that when colors are the same, this loop gets lost.

I am making a program to use it in game, as my school project. It needs to detect where are you, and I am detecting it by colours, specifically ImageGrab library.

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

time.sleep(1)
px=ImageGrab.grab().load()               

x = 20

y = 20

color = px[x, y]

location = '(255, 255, 255)'

if (color == location):
    print('you are here')


if not (color == location):
    print('you arent here')
```

Even tho the pixel is white it tells everytime that it is not, which isn`t correct. What is wrong? It really looks odd for me.

Comment: What does `print(color)` and `print(type(color))` output? Does it output a `str` or  a `tuple`?  If it outputs a `tuple` then `if color == location` will fail because you are comparing a `str` to a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the function `ImageGrab.grab().load()` returns is an *array of tuples of ints*.

In other words, each pixel is a tuple, which looks like this:

```
In [4]: im = ImageGrab.grab().load()

In [5]: im[0,0]
Out[5]: (24, 24, 25, 255)
```

which contain the values `(red,green,blue,alpha)` in the type `int`.

You are trying to compare a tuple of numbers with a string, `location = '(255, 255, 255)'`. It will fail, because you can't compare a string (which is an array of characters) with a number.

For example,

```
In [12]: 2 == '2'
Out[12]: False
```

I won't solve your homework for you, but maybe this will help:

```
In [14]: location = (255,255,255)

In [15]: color = (255,255,255,0)

In [16]: [color[i] == location[i] for i in range(3)]
Out[16]: [True, True, True]

In [17]: all([color[i] == location[i] for i in range(3)])
Out[17]: True
```

Comment: Give this man a cookie!



Yes it worked, I noticed that in location variable there are spaces between numbres, this is what was glitching the if instructions.

It is funny tho because if there weren`t 2 variables but just 1 in instruction then everything was working great, no matter if there were spaces or not.